# Why is Minecraft slower when using Linux?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, linux

I recently installed Linux Mint on my MacBook Air, but Minecraft seems to be much slower (lower FPS) than when I played it on Mac OS. Why would Minecraft be slower on Linux? Is there any way to make it faster? Even turning down the Video Settings doesn't do much. I'm using Java Edition 1.15.2, and my computer has 4GB of RAM.

Comment: The most likely reason is lack, or poor GPU acceleration support in its drivers, stemming from Apple's outright hostility to any other OS on their machines than MacOS, and keeping the specifications of their hardware a secret.

Comment: Is it possible to make Minecraft faster, or will I have to dual-boot Mac OS to play Minecraft?